# WPEWebkit and Arabic font issue

Tags: raspberry-pi3, yocto

I'm testing the [WPEWebkit](https://github.com/WebPlatformForEmbedded/WPEWebKit) with arabic website and I have an issue with some website and I don't know what's wrong.

This one won't render the font (rectangles) : https://www3.nhk.or.jp/nhkworld/ar/news/

this jsfiddle neither : https://jsfiddle.net/samoud/qa3cfjdf/6/

or this one (with google fonts) : https://jsfiddle.net/samoud/qa3cfjdf/7/

**CSS**

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Amiri');
.arabic {
   font-family: 'Amiri', serif;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="arabic">
قصة رجل يعثر على والديه بعد رحلة بحث دامت 74 عاما
</div>
```

**BUT this one will render as expected** : http://www.aljazeera.net/portal

Do you have any idea please ?

Comment: I don't know if you solved your issue, but every websites looks fine to me (no rectangles). I checked chrome browser & firefox.

Comment: You can check your fonts by load website [Google Fonts](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Open+Sans?selection.family=Open+Sans) and test in `Languages Option` support first. See what options suit with you - try to change Font Family of your language.